# Как создавались мнемоники Языка ассемблера из двоичных кодов?

Tags: ассемблер

Подскажите, где копать информацию, или, пожалуйста, объясните, как из команды, например, сложения на двоичном коде `0000 0100` создали мнемонику `ADD`?
Кажется чистой магией, что из тумблеров и дырок/отсутствия дырок на перфокарте создали вводимый на дисплее текст, который трансформируется в цифры.

Comment: `ADD` это просто человекодружелюбное название/представление `00000100` в контексте команд.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Изначально программисты писали программы в машинных кодах, составляя длинные последовательности из нулей и единиц. Машинные коды в буквальном смысле представляют высокие и низкие уровни напряжения на “ножках” микросхемы процессора. Внутренняя структура логических элементов микросхемы из которой образуются [арифметико-логическое устройство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) и диктовала то, какие уровни должны были быть выставлены на управляющих пинах.
Программирование в машинных кодах было очень трудоёмким и порождало огромное количество ошибок, дебаг которых был адской задачей. Очень быстро стало понятно, что процесс поиска нужной машинной команды для определённого действия можно автоматизировать и в 50-х годах начали применять мнемонический язык ассемблер. Он позволил представлять машинные кода в более удобном для людей виде.
Для того чтобы не запоминать кучу машинных команд программисты используют  *транслятор* который "подставляет" вместо мнемоник `ADD` определённые значения типа `0000 0100`. Грубо говоря как операция "Заменить" в текстовых редакторах.

Для более подробного понимания могу посоветовать книгу "Цифровая схемотехника и архитектура компьютера" Харрис Д.М.

Так же есть прекрасный курс “NAND2tetris” (на английском, бесплатный), который позволяет пройти все этапы проектирование своего микропроцессора от базовых логических операций до компьютерной игры, проходя все уровни абстракций.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что используется кодировка ASCII для представления этих машинных команд в буквенных мнемониках, а транслятор же это мэппит в машинный код?
За книгу огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Все было не совсем так, если уж идти к истокам. Люди изобрели цифр и операции над ними задолго до.... Вначале были камни, потом веревки, косточки и счеты. Над эими элементами делали всевозможные операции - складывали и вычитали). Создав машину её заставили выполнять понятные для людей операции - сложения, вычитания, переноса, сдвига (ADD, SUB, MOV, SHIFT, PUS, POP). Для машины их закодировали двоичным кодом, (скорее всего как в голову взбрело). А для людей, чтоб облегчить им программирование придумали трансляторы с эквивалентов понятных людям слов слов в код. JAMP - C3 ;)